# How do I return the Social Persona for a Person Account, related to a Case?

Tags: soql, person-accounts, social-content

I'm trying to query my salesforce Org, which has 'Person Accounts' enabled, and return a Case, the related PersonAccount and any Social Persona related to that Person Account, but I can't determine the relationship, from Case to Social Persona as the latter appears to only be related to Contact.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have now worked this out by just using SOQL to get the Social Persona data.  There is a ParentId field and when you take that id and plug it back into salesforce, you get a Person Account.  So the answer is - you can;t do what I was attempting to do, you will need two queries, one for Case and PersonAccount, and then a second to return Social Persona, based on al the PersonAccount ids you have from the first query.